# when we create a container within a storage account, how do we know whether we create to Blob, or Queues or other data objects?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-storage-account

Very recently I started learning Azure Data Factory from youtube resource. As part of learning, I created a container under a storage account; while going through the creation steps, there is a drop-down for the label: public access level, with options 1. private (no anonymous access), 2. Blob (anonymous read access for blob only), 3. Container(anonymous access for containers and blobs). This is where I got a doubt as follows: when we create a container under a storage account, is it specific to type of data object, say, Blob, Queues, Files and etc? Further, when I tried to search for creating containers microsoft documentation, the documentation is associated with Blob documentation, not just containers in storage account. Please find the attachment of the screenshot.[image]

Would anyone please help me understand the scenario.

Thank you for your time and kind concern;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A container is just for blobs. Files and queues have their own structure:

[image]

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction#blob-storage-resources) explain is very well:

[image]

When configuring the public access level you can configure the whole container and all blobs inside to be public accessible or for blobs only or not at all.

Comment: Thank you, Peter; the info is very helpful!